# Performing an ArcMap Python scripted tool based on whether a field is populated or not

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap

My question is if I'm running the `ArcMap Dissolve` tool through a Python script, how can I tell it to check for attributes in one field, and if that field is empty, to perform the tool on another field.

To be more specific, I would like the `Dissolve` tool to check for route numbers in a field called [`rt_shrt_nm`] (which are provided when the route name is a numerical value). But if that field is empty (which is sometimes is if the field has textual route names) to perform the tool on the [`rt_long_nm`] field instead.

This is what I'm working with now, just to give you a better idea, even though I know its probably wildly wrong:

```
if [rt_shrt_nm] is null:
    arcpy.Dissolve_management(OutShapesFCname, outGDB, ["rt_long_nm"], "", "", "")
elif:
    arcpy.Dissolve_management(OutShapesFCname, outGDB, ["rt_shrt_nm"], "", "", "")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a list from the rt_long_nm field with a list comprehension and use that for the logic check. The list comprehension searches for all values except for `None` and adds those to a list. If the length of the list equals 0, perform some action, else perform another action.

```
import arcpy

OutShapesFCname = r'C:\path\to\fc'

vals = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(OutShapesFCname, ["rt_long_nm"]) if row[0] is not None]

if len(vals) == 0:
        arcpy.Dissolve_management(OutShapesFCname, outGDB, ["rt_long_nm"], "", "", "")
else:
        arcpy.Dissolve_management(OutShapesFCname, outGDB, ["rt_shrt_nm"], "", "", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column, calculate the values from the primary column then select all the nulls and calculate from the secondary column. Then use the new column for dissolve.